# Multiple Where clause with decryption

Tags: mysql, sql

Would a query like this basically decrypt the usernames for each where condition or just once and apply that to each condition?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
WHERE (
    CONCAT_WS(
        ' ', 
        AES_DECRYPT(TableA.FirstName, "fnkey"), 
        AES_DECRYPT(TableA.LastName, "lnkey")
    ) LIKE '%RAY%' 
    OR 
    CONCAT_WS(
        ' ', 
        AES_DECRYPT(TableA.LastName, "lnkey"), 
        AES_DECRYPT(TableA.FirstName, "fnkey")
    ) LIKE '%RAY%'
);
```

Comment: Might it be faster to `SELECT` the decrypted names, then filter the results in whichever programming language you are using?

Comment: Why do you want to use this because LIKE %% syntax always messes up your indexes. so a complete table scan is always required.. this would really be slow if the table is large.

Comment: wouldn't just the decrypting require a complete table scan anyway?

Comment: On another note, would it be worth it to have a field for sorted order index, so if you want the first 5, you can look at that number instead of having to decrypt the entire table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell if the function is evaluated once for each row or more. It depends on the query optimizer. You could establish it by benchmark.

Anyway, this query is very inefficient. It will do a full table scan and calculate this function for each row. You cannot use an index here. You would not implement this query on a table with more than a couple of rows.