# PHP full text search on associative array

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I am encrypting and decrypting my MySQL contact table in PHP. That is all fine and everything but I am making the data grid so that it has a single search box that does a full text search on all the columns. The problem now is that the search is being done against the encrypted data and not the original data.

So I am forced to do the full text search in PHP. This requires me to iterate over each row, but I am doing this anyway because I need to decrypt it.

My concern lies with the speed at which my code does the full text search, I want to know if there is a better, faster way to do this?

```
$result = Some PDO query that does a PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, query has about 8 columns
$searchPhrase = strtolower($searchPhrase);
$aes = new AES(DATABASE_KEY, DATABASE_IV);
$count = count($result);

for($ii = 0; $ii <$count; $ii++ )
{
    $result[$ii]["ContactName"] = $aes->Decrypt($result[$ii]["ContactName"]);
    $result[$ii]["ContactDescription"] = $aes->Decrypt($result[$ii]["ContactDescription"]);
    /*More encrypted columns*/


    if (!empty($searchPhrase)) //Only do search when search phrase not empty
    {        
        $filterRow = array_slice($result[$ii], 3); // Do not take first 3 columns       
        $data = strtolower(implode("", $filterRow)); //Flaten row as one string, all lowercase
        if (strpos($data, $searchPhrase) === FALSE) //Now doing elimentation from array if not match
            unset($result[$ii]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only [secure and efficient way to search encrypted data in PHP + MySQL](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption#index-encrypted-information) is via exact match, using a technique called blind indexing.

1. Store `E(M, K1) || H(E(M, K1), K2)` (e.g. a message encrypted with [`defuse/php-encryption`](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption)) in one column
2. Store `H(M, K3)` in a second column

In pseudo-code

```
$cipher = Crypto::encrypt($message, $encryptionKey); // takes care of K1 and K2 for you
$blind_idx = hash_hmac('sha384', $message, $unrelatedKey); // K3
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm still going down the rabbit hole you provided. Looks very interesting will look into it more.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, encrypting database columns with symmetric encryption like AES doesn't add to your information security very much. That's because the `DATABASE_KEY` must be available to your programs. So a cybercriminal who penetrates your system will easily find and steal your key, and then easily steal your data.

If your columns' values are encrypted your database system can't generate a useful fulltext index.  Therefore, the substring search strategy in your question is close to optimal.

But, seriously, spend your time and money on a good firewall. Protect your database and web servers from intruders, rather than trying to stop intruders from stealing columns of data once they have taken over your systems.

Comment: The reason I'm doing the encryption PHP side is so that if the Database does fall in the wrong hands it won't be compromised because they need to breach my server first and get the encryption key from my PHP script. But I do get your point, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the mysql function `AES_DECRYPT`. Essentially, you could retrieve all of the data from the database in plain format or run queries against it or just tell mysql to go row by row to decrypt the data before comparing your value with it. Take a look at the following:

[MYSQL SELECT WHERE LIKE WITH AES_ENCRYPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613289/mysql-select-where-like-with-aes-encrypt)

[Multiple Where clause with decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407075/multiple-where-clause-with-decryption)

Comment: I want to keep Encryption PHP side, and your links only use the MySQL functions that also do it linearly, trying to avoid O(n)